# Group Policy add firewall rule error: The parameter is incorrect

Tags: active-directory, group-policy, windows-firewall

I have had similar errors to this one on multiple configuration options in the group policy editor.

When I am trying to add an outbound firewall rule (block outgoing UDP 17500) under:

***(Computer configuration > Policies > Windows Settings > Security Settings > Windows Firewall with Advanced Security > Windows Firewall with Advanced Security - LDAP://CN...)***

It results in the following error:

[image: GPO Firewall Error]

Which from what it appears, the actual firewall rule itself is parsed correctly, however I cannot find anyone else having this particular error on the internet dealing with adding GPO configurations.

The closest I've found is that there might be a replication error between DC's however there is only one DC in the environment.

Anyone else run into this before?

Thanks.

Comment: What version of Windows is Group Policy Management Console displaying the error?

Comment: It's running Windows server 2008 r2

Comment: UPDATE: (Comment since I can't edit question) When I created a new GPO and linked it to the OU I was able to add a single firewall rule then it gave me the same error when trying to add another rule in the same new GPO.

Comment: On the computer where GPMC is displaying the error, are you able to add the same rule in the Windows Firewall Advanced management console?

Comment: Yes, just tested it. If it helps, another similar case is when I try to configure anything under Security Settings > Local Policies > Security options. There it says: "The parameter is incorrect. Failed to save ... Make sure that this object exists" (I've checked the path at ... and it does exist)